# How to avoid Haskell space leak?

Tags: haskell, memory-leaks

## Context

I've started leaning Haskell not long ago by solving this year's Advent of Code tasks.

While solving [Part 2 of Day 17](https://adventofcode.com/2017/day/17) I've ran into a nasty memory leak (space leak) -- I think.

<sub>(Here's the full [README](https://github.com/kohanyirobert/advent-of-code-2017/blob/e748d5f46007c85fcf1da6c8d87a743139edb45b/17/README.txt) including Part 2, one can only access it after solving Part 1.)</sub>

My solution works and it runs fine, but only with a dirty little hack, which forces Haskell to evaluate an intermediate computation every now and then.

I'm using `traceShow` to print the intermediate state to the console after every 5000 iterations (please see here [the actual code](https://github.com/kohanyirobert/advent-of-code-2017/blob/e748d5f46007c85fcf1da6c8d87a743139edb45b/17/Day17.hs#L46)). This way the program finishes in a reasonable time and doesn't use too much memory.

The problem: if I remove this (not printing the intermediate state at all, only the last state) the program eats up all available memory. :(

I've started out with using `iterate` and then I've read that using that can cause stuff like what I'm noticing. I've replaced it. Nothing. Tried different folds (`foldl`, `foldl'`, etc.). Nothing. I'm not sure at this point what can cause this although my guess is that at some point there's some not so evident lazy evaluation going on.

My question: how can I avoid this? What causes this in my case?

Thank you for your time and insight. Oh, and I'm pretty sure that there are shorter, sweeter solutions to this problem, but currently I'm only interested in what causes the memory leak in my case.

## Testing

I've isolated the part of the code where I notice this error.

```
type Count = Int
type StepSize = Int
type Value = Int
type Position = Int
type Size = Int

data Buffer = Buffer Size Position (Maybe Value)
  deriving Show

data Spinlock = Spinlock StepSize !Position !Value Buffer
  deriving Show

updateBuffer :: Position -> Value -> Buffer -> Buffer
updateBuffer position value (Buffer size trackedPosition trackedValue)
  | position == trackedPosition = Buffer nextSize trackedPosition (Just value)
  | otherwise = Buffer nextSize trackedPosition trackedValue
  where nextSize = size + 1

stepSpinlock :: Count -> Spinlock -> Spinlock
stepSpinlock count spinlock@(Spinlock stepSize position value buffer)
  | count == 0 = spinlock
  | otherwise = stepSpinlock nextCount newSpinlock
  where (Buffer size _ _) = buffer
        nextCount = count - 1
        nextPosition = ((position + stepSize) `mod` size) + 1
        nextValue = value + 1
        newBuffer = updateBuffer nextPosition nextValue buffer
        newSpinlock = Spinlock stepSize nextPosition nextValue newBuffer

main = do
  let stepSize = 371
      buffer = Buffer 1 0 Nothing
      spinlock = Spinlock stepSize 0 0 buffer
      (Spinlock _ _ _ (Buffer _ _ (Just value))) = stepSpinlock (50000000 - 1) spinlock
  print $ value
```

I'm running this with `stack` (`lts-10.1`), GHC 8.2.2.

Running this eats up all of my memory and fails miserably with a *cannot allocate memory* error after a little while.

If I replace this

```
  | otherwise = stepSpinlock nextCount newSpinlock
```

with this

```
  | otherwise = stepSpinlock nextCount $ if count `mod` 5000 == 0
                                         then traceShow newSpinlock newSpinlock
                                         else newSpinlock
```

it runs in reasonable time.
and recompile with `stack ghc Part2.hs` then run again `./Part2 < input.txt`.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Well, I've tried clarifying it, hope this enough. It's not minimal ... yet, but complete and verifiable! I'm not sure how to make it more minimal currently, because I can't narrow down the problem (mostly because lack of experience with Haskell I think).

Comment: It's not complete. The code you posted here is just fragments of a function. There isn't even a `main`.

Comment: I don't have time this year to make it more complete, will do so when I have the time. I could write a `main` function with minimal code if I knew what, which part exactly, which statements, what syntax, etc. causes the problem, but I don't. The help section defines a question being "complete" as one that contains _all information necessary to reproduce the problem_. I think my question does try hard to do so. Will knowing that the `Part2.hs` source contains the `main` function help to understand it? I can update the question later.

Comment: A complete question contains all the necessary code, not just a bunch of links to other sites. I'm not going to click around in someone's github account, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works:

```
{-# language BangPatterns #-}

...

stepSpinlock :: Count -> Spinlock -> Spinlock
stepSpinlock count spinlock@(Spinlock !stepSize !position !value !buffer)
...
```

On each iteration, you update `value` and `buffer` without doing anything with them, hence the thunk accumulation. Alternatively, I recommend just using `{-# language Strict #-}`. I also note that `CircularBuffer` is not used at all during the program run with `input.txt`.

Comment: `{-# language STRICT #-}` is a very big (and somewhat experimental) hammer. Making the type strict in its fields would definitely be worth considering.

Comment: Hmm, thanks, _thunk accumulation_ was the key-phrase for me. Also what @dfeuer mentions seems milder for me, I like that approach better, but thanks for the pointers! Oh, and `CircularBuffer` is used exclusively in the first part of the solution.